# How to Add Row Value from one DataFrame to Another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I'm trying to iterate through the table, and copy/append a row to another table based on its' column value. So if the value in the 3rd column is -1, the entire row is copied to another table (t_neg1).

The table:
[image: table image]

Can someone please look at my code, and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

eps = 4.3


model  = DBSCAN(eps            = eps,
                min_samples    = 210,
                metric         = 'euclidean'
                )

data = model.fit(plotting_data)


X          = plotting_data['X']
Y          = plotting_data['Y']

clusters = data.fit_predict(plotting_data)
print(clusters)

clust_df = pd.DataFrame(plotting_data)
clusters = (clust_df[data.labels_ != -1])
Label    = data.fit_predict(clusters)

cluster_table = clusters
table                        = [cluster_table, Label]
cluster_table                = pd.concat(table,  axis = 1, sort = False)
col                          = list(["X", "Y", "Cluster ID"])


# **This part below here is causing me issues.**
t_neg1 = pd.DataFrame()
t_0    = pd.DataFrame()

# I'm sures there's a better way to handle this but I'll look into it later
i = 0
for i in range(len(cluster_table)):
    if cluster_table['Cluster ID'].loc == -1:
        t_neg1.copy(cluster_table.loc[i])
    if cluster_table['Cluster ID'].loc == 0:
        t_0.copy(cluster_table.loc[i])


        i += 1

print(t_neg1)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! My first concern is `.loc ==-1` in your code, which doesn't mean...anything, as far as I can tell. If I understand your problem correctly, you've (thankfully) worked way harder than you need to. You can use boolean masking to select all rows that meet one or more criteria, e.g., `t_neg1 = cluster_table[cluster_table['Cluster ID']==-1]`

Comment: Oh wow, this worked perfectly! Thanks @G.Anderson!

Comment: Cheers! It may be worth a quick skim through the [pandas indexing and filtering docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to familiarize yourself with boolean indexing (the subseciton I linked to) as well as `filter`, `query`, `.loc[]`, and `.iloc[]`